# How to change url on forwarding to a view?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

On clicking logout button page redirected to homepage. But the url is not changing,

my local homepage url: localhost:8080/merr/login.html

after logout i want the url to change to : localhost:8080/merr/login.html

but it is showing: localhost:8080/merr/logout.html

controller

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/logout", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String logOut(Map<String, Object> model, HttpSession session) {
        User user = new User();
        model.put("user", user); 
        model.put("userId", 0);
        session.invalidate();
        return "login";
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no redirection here. Only a forward to the `login` view. To have a redirection, you would need a view name starting with `redirect:`. See [the documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.4.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-redirecting) for details.

Comment: `return redirect:/login.html`. Have you at least clicked the link, read, and tried something?